# the Implementation of isPlainObject function in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

Recently, I'm reading the source code of redux. But, I can't understand this code in [isPlainObject](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/isPlainObject.js) function:

```
/**
 * @param {any} obj The object to inspect.
 * @returns {boolean} True if the argument appears to be a plain object.
 */
export default function isPlainObject(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) return false

  let proto = obj
  while (Object.getPrototypeOf(proto) !== null) {
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)
  }

  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === proto
}
```

I think it work like the code below ,could you explain it for me?

```
return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype || Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === null
```

Comment: Just to note, your test passes all the tests put in place for `isPlainObject` by redux, except when `obj` is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: If you look through the history of the file you'll find some useful details as to why it was changed: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/commits/master/src/utils/isPlainObject.js

Comment: Uh,i mean my test replaces the code: ` let proto = obj ....return Object.getPrototypeOf...`

Comment: I almost understood its role.just for some edge cases(Cross-iframe,cross-realm).Thanks~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it works like the code `return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype`

Yes, that's the basic idea.

> `… || Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === null`

No, that is not what it checks for.

> Could you explain?

A comparison for equality with `Object.prototype` only works for objects that actually inherit from `Object.prototype`. This is not always the case for plain objects though, which might come from another realm - like an iframe - and inherit from the other realm's `Object.prototype`. To detect these, the code basically first searches for an `Object.prototype`-like (i.e. inheriting from `null`) object in the prototype chain of the argument, and then checks whether the argument directly inherits from that.

Of course, the whole looping thing is quite unnecessary, they could (should) simplify to

```
export default function isPlainObject(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) return false

  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  return proto !== null && Object.getPrototypeOf(proto) === null;
}
```

Comment: See the discussion in [redux#2599](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/2599#issuecomment-342849867) for the reasoning behind this particular implementation.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for the confirmation! Still doesn't explain why they used a loop though :-)

Comment: You'd have to ask Tim directly on that, but my vague assumption is that it's to ensure that we really are dealing with the root prototypes, rather than any potential subclassing that might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the function states it looks for if an object is plain or not.

The plain objects in javascript are Objects created by {}, new Object() or Object.create(null). Here is a more detailed explanation of plain object https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-plainObject-in-JavaScript/answer/%E9%A3%9E-%E7%BD%97-1.

All we trying to do is looking for if the given object's prototype is equal to `Object.prototype` or it equals to `null`.

In code

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype || Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === null
```

In case you want to know why we have null check, when we create an object with `Object.create(null)` the prototype of
it has a null value. In other words:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(null)) === null => true
```

Now, if we could get the desired answer as easily as the above snippet, why they put a while loop that makes the understanding of the code harder? Of course, the only reason is not to make it harder :)

When we try to access variables across iframes, the prototype of the plain objects created in the file that imports the iframe and the framed file are not equal. This is because they run in separate environments. In other words, prototypes of the objects are still pointing to the Object constructors, but the Object constructors are not equal to each other.

To better understand, we can demo it. Create 4 files in the same folder: index.html frame.html index.js frame.js.

Note: To make the below example work without browsers block cross-origin frames, you should put them in a local server. Or just use vscode Live Server extension

Below index.html imports frame.html as iframe. It also imports index.js which only contains a global variable `plainObject`. Also, frame.html only imports frame.js.

In frame.js we reach the `plainObject` variable as `window.parent.plainObject`. Here `plainObject` lives in the context of index.html and index.js and as we see in the second line `console.log` statement: the prototype of `window.parent.plainObject` is not equal to `Object.prototype` of frame.js context.

It is exactly why redux implemented the function with a while loop. In frame.js, from line 3 to line 5 we have the same while loop as redux have. After that loop we can safely check if the `plainObject` of parent is a plain object or not by looking if there is any other proto constructor between it and getPrototype result of it. The console.log statement in line 6 checks it.

The content of each file:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <iframe src="frame.html">
  </body>
</html>`
```

frame.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <body>
   <script src='frame.js'></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var plainObject = {}
```

frame.js

```
let parentPlainObject = window.parent.plainObject;

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(parentPlainObject) === Object.prototype) // this is equal to false because parentPlainObject's prototype is in another environment

while(Object.getPrototypeOf(parentPlainObject) !== null) {
  parentPlainObject = Object.getPrototypeOf(parentPlainObject)
}

console.log(parentPlainObject === Object.getPrototypeOf(window.parent.plainObject)) // now we can test if parentPlainObject is a plain one or has another proto constructor in prototype chain
```