# What is considered a plain object?

Tags: javascript, redux

In JS, but in particular for redux, what is considered a plain object?

Is for example the following also considered a plain object?

```
let a = {
  b: {
    c: 'd'
  }
};
```

Redux states that actions must be plain objects, but what if I have the following data comming in after a while and it needs to be added to the state.

```
let payload = {
  all: ['john', 'jane'],
  byId: {
    john: {
      name: 'john',
      age: 23
    },
    jane: {
      name: 'jane',
      age: 40
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have an action:

```
function userLoad(payload) {
  return { type: USER_LOAD, payload }
}
```

But if payload isn't a plain object this isn't considered good practise. How to handle such cases.

Comment: The function redux uses to check whether it has a plain object may be useful: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/3a17aef0468e279cba048411f8f91dce07c55a7e/src/utils/isPlainObject.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain object or POJO (plain javascript object) is an object created by the following manners:

```js
let foo = {prop1: 1}  // object literal
let bar = new Object(); // new object syntax
```

The difference with a POJO and an object created via a constructor function is the following:

```js
function Person (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

let me  = new Person('willem')  // this object is not a POJO


console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(me) === Person.prototype); // prototype is Person


let POJO = {};

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(POJO) === Object.prototype); // POJO prototype is always Object not the prototype property of the constructor functoin. This is the difference
```

Comment: But what if the object has references to other plain objects, is it still considered a POJO? Some testing with the above function gives me true, so I'd say yes.

Comment: I would say so yes, POJO has prototype of the Object object

Comment: the main purpose of a POJO is that is copy-efficient and predictable, if not some time if could have deep copy performance problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it is considered a a plain object, see below snippet.

```js
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) return false

  let proto = obj
  while (Object.getPrototypeOf(proto) !== null) {
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)
  }

  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === proto
}

let obj = {
  a: {
    b: 'sss',
    c: ['ss', 'sss']
  }
}

console.log(isPlainObject(obj));
```

Comment: (Also notice that [this code could be simplified a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726564/1048572))